# table created by GORM/Hibernate is missing foreign key

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have the following domain class in my app

```
class OauthProfile {

    Date dateCreated
    Map<String, String> claims

    static mapping = {
        claims indexColumn: [name: 'name'], type: 'text'     
    }
}
```

The claims map results in the creation of this table

```
mysql> describe oauth_profile_claims;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| claims     | bigint(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| name       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| claims_elt | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Notice that there is no foreign key relationship between `oauth_profile` and `oauth_profile_claims`, but I think there ought to be, is this a bug? I'm using Grails 2.5.2.

Comment: Did you drop db and recreate it after making changes in your domain class? Is it possible that these are just artefects from hot-deployed changes in code?

Comment: @Michal_Szulc I tried dropping and recreating the DB, but it makes no difference